# Cannot read property 'reduce' of undefined in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**HeaderCartButton.js**

```
import CartIcon from "../Cart/CartIcon";
import classes from "./HeaderCartButton.module.css";
import { useContext } from "react";
import CartContext from "../../store/Cart-Context";

const HeaderCartButton = ({ onShow }) => {
  const cartCtx = useContext(CartContext);

  const numofCartItems = cartCtx.items.reduce((curNum, item) => {
    return curNum + item.amount;
  }, 0);

  return (
    <button className={classes.button} onClick={onShow}>
      <span className={classes.icon}>
        <CartIcon />
      </span>
      <span>Your Cart</span>
      <span className={classes.badge}>{numofCartItems}</span>
    </button>
  );
};

export default HeaderCartButton;
```

****CartContext.js****

```
import React from "react";

const CartContext = React.createContext({
  items: [],
  totalAmount: 0,
  addItem: (item) => {},
  removeItem: (id) => {},
});


export default CartContext;
```

These are the two files. How to remove the error? I think my code is correct. What is the reason of the error? How can I solve this issue? please help

Comment: Are you using a `CartContext.Provider` anywhere? EDIT: If you've rendered a `CartContext.Provider` without a value for `items` it would give you this error.

Comment: No, I am not using anywhere. I have used this on the Cart button to reduce the added same items as a object. I am building a WebApp to order Fooditems.

Comment: In that case, nothing is wrong with the code you've shown. So the problem must lie in the code you haven't shown. Try and make a reproducible example (like on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/))

Comment: I am noticing a typo - you are importing `Cart-Context` but you've named your file `CartContext.js`. Please make sure you are looking at the correct files, this is probably just a typo in your question, though.

Comment: What do you get when you `console.log(cartCtx)`?

Comment: I am getting error in the console.log also. I have aslo tried to use const numofCartItems = cartCtx.items.length;    But error is same. It cannot read property length on this.

Comment: What's the error? Also, please show the output of this **exact** statement - `console.log(cartCtx)` (**DO NOT** do `console.log(cartCtx.items)`)